# .Net Core Web API response with multiple properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I am designing an API endpoint and planning to send the response with 2 values ( one with total no of records and second with list of records ) The controller action is designed like below

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("users_bycat")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetUsersByCat([FromQuery] int categoryId )
    {       
        var query = db_context.Users.Select(a => a).Where(p => p.CategoryId == categoryId);                   
        var result = await query.ExecuteAsync();

        return Ok(
               new
               {
                   totalRecords = result.Count(),
                   users = result.ToList()
               }
            );
    }
```

When i am calling this api endpoint, i am getting response like below

```
    {
        "totalRecords": 37652,
        "users": []
    }
```

The users array is empty and i try like below   , and managed to get the list as response , but i would like to add count as well to the response

```
    return Ok(  result.ToList());
```

How can i ensure i will get both totalRecords and users List as a part of response

Comment: You don't need to call `query.ExecuteAsync()` as `query.ToList()` will fetch the result, in fact, you can remove the `.Select(a => a)` also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ExecuteAsync()` is redundant as an `IQueryable` is materialised upon calling `.ToList()`. Additionally, calling `.Count()` will execute an additional database query so it's more efficient to move this call onto the `List`. The exception to this would be if you were implementing paging.

The below should function as required:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("users_bycat")]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetUsersByCat([FromQuery] int categoryId )
{       
    var results = await db_context.Users
      .Where(p => p.CategoryId == categoryId)
      .ToListAsync();
    
    var dto = new
    {
      totalRecords = results.Count,
      users = results
    };

    return Ok(dto);
}
```